# Show a value in case of NULL in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following `NullableConverter` class. However when I run my application, it does not show anything in the `TextView`, how I could able to show 0 if the value is null? Is it possible to do it in the `axml`?

```
public class NullableValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

and inside my view:

```
local:MvxBind="Text Age,Converter=Nullable;"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1: FallbackValue**

You can use `FallbackValue` for this.

```
local:MvxBind="Text Age, Converter=Nullable, FallbackValue='0';"
```

Regarding to the [Spec](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#fallback-values) it does just fall back, if the there is no value (null is a value). So you have to change you converter to:

```
public class NullableValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        }
        return value;
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Option 2: simple return in Convert**

Or you can simply return `0` instead of throwing an exception and then don't use `FallbackValue`

```
public class NullableValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
        {
            return "0";
        }
        return value;
    }
    // ...
}
```

But this converter is then not so generic anymore.

**Option 3: ConverterParameter**

The 3rd option is to pass the fallback via the `ConverterParameter`

```
public class NullableValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
        {
            return parameter;
        }
        return value;
    }
    // ...
}
```

And bind like this:

```
local:MvxBind="Text Age, Converter=Nullable, ConverterParameter='0';"
```

But then you should give the converter a more meaningful name like `NullableWithFallbackValaueConverter` or whatever.

**Side note**

Try to use `MvxValueConverter<TFrom, TTo>` if possible. So you do not have to cast inside of `Convert` and `ConvertBack`. For this particular converter it would make not much sense. But just in case you didn't know.

**Side note #2**

I can imagine that this approach will be criticized by some guys, because the disadvantage of this approach is, that the shown value depends on the data binding in your view. And this you have to write multiple times (e.g. in iOS and Android). Setting a fallback value if the actual value is `null` is more a concern of the ViewModel.